# Rebuild specific object based on condition

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to modify gnu makefile of a large projects that has generic/pattern specific rules.

The makefile is compiling and linking in separate rules. I have a specific need that if a certain condition pass at link time, then i want to call the compile rule again before linking again. Sample issue from makefile is as below,

```
    $(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp
    @echo Compiling: $<
    $(q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(REV) $(CXX_INCLUDE_PATH) -o $@ $<

    $(link_files) :
    @echo Linking $@
    $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ %.o
    ifeq (1,1)
    #condition pass so I want to call generic above ompilation rule again
       ?????
    else
      $(warning Do Nothing)
    endif
```

Can someone please help me on how I can call generic compilation rule again either recursively or otherwise.

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you want the object files to be prerequisites of the linking rule? In that case calling the compilation rules again will do nothing, since the object files will already be up to date.

Comment: Thanks. I can add object files as link rule dependency or i can remove resulting link files before calling the compilation rule again. Can you help me with the original question on how can i call invoke compilation rule again inside link rule.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how Make works. It's easy to reinvoke the compilation rule, if you have a list of the desired object files, but I don't see any sense in doing so. Could you tell us *why* you want to rebuild the object files?

Comment: Yeah, i haven't worked a lot on makefiles so my question or use case might be crazy. I have to check the md5sum of my linked object with one of the historic md5sum of same object saved in separate manifest file. If both md5sums doesn't match than i want to reinvoke the compilation with a new revision number as indicated by $(REV) variable. Is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: That's... horrible. I find it almost impossible to imagine a scenario in which keeping object files under version control is a good idea. I understand that you may not have the authority to change this scheme, but you *must* be aware of how bad it is (and that you can compile the same source code twice and get two object files that are not identical). If you still want the answer to the original question, I'll post it with caveats-- but in that case please tell me whether you have a list of the desired object files.

Comment: Thanks .. I understand your point that its not the neatest solution but somehow I have a use-case where using version control is not a possibility. I perfectly agree with your comments but I would still like to find a solution to the above problem and try to use it for one of my custom needs. So this is how I am finding the objects in the link rule in something like, $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $(sort $(filter %.o, $^)) and passing objects to link in the link rule. Kindly let me know if we can use this information to reinvoke right compilation rule for that specific objects.

Comment: I failed to state in my last comment that I am not using version control rather using my own version scheme where i save historic md5sums in a manifest file and want to change revision number only if there is a code change (based on new md5sum).

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** get the basic makefile working. Maybe you have this already, but here's an outline:

```
OBJECTS := $(obj_dir)/foo.o $(obj_dir)/bar.o $(obj_dir)/baz.o
# You MUST have a list like this somewhere, constructed somehow.

$(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp
    @echo Compiling: $<
    $(q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(REV) $(CXX_INCLUDE_PATH) -o $@ $<

$(link_files) : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking $@
    $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Be sure that this works correctly before proceeding. In particular, be sure that you can pass Make a value for `REV` in the command line, like this:

```
make REV=123
```

**Step 2:** test the recursive call. Make it unconditional at first.

```
$(link_files) : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking $@
    $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    $(MAKE) REV=$(NEWREV) $(OBJECTS)
```

**Step 3:** test the conditional.

```
$(link_files) : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking $@
    $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    $(MAKE) REV=$(NEWREV) $(OBJECTS)
    if [ 1 -eq 2 ];\
      then echo Do Something; \
     else \
      echo Do Nothing; \
     fi
```

Notice that this is a *shell* output statement in a *shell* conditional, not a *Make* output statement in a *Make* conditional. (Make statements tend to be evaluated before any rule runs.) There is a TAB in front of the `if`, but the whitespace in front of the other lines in the conditional is just spaces.

**Step 4:** put it together.

```
$(link_files) : $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking $@
    $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    $(MAKE) REV=$(NEWREV) $(OBJECTS)
    if [ 1 -eq 2 ];\
      then $(MAKE) REV=$(NEWREV) $(OBJECTS); \
     else \
      echo Do Nothing; \
     fi
```

Comment: Thanks Beta. I haven't tested your solution but I was able to create a similar Makefile which follows more or less same methodology but i introduced a few more custom rules so that I can recursively call those specific rules based on my new revision for that specific object.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Beta, this sounds crazy.

But if you just want to do it anyway, it's pretty simple.  Here's the thing, though, you have to write the test as a *shell* test, inside the recipe.  You can't use a *make* test (`ifeq` etc.)  Then you can invoke a recursive make to build the file, and use the `-W` flag to force it to be rebuilt.  Something like (assuming the file you want to rebuild is `foo.cpp`:

```
$(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_base)/%.cpp
        @echo Compiling: $<
        $(q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(REV) $(CXX_INCLUDE_PATH) -o $@ $<

$(link_files) :
        @echo Linking $@
        $(q)$(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ %.o
        if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then \
           $(MAKE) -W $(src_base)/foo.cpp $(obj_dir)/foo.o || exit 1; \
        else; \
           echo do nothing; \
        fi
```

Comment: Thanks .. I haven't tested it yet but I have a small confusion in this. We are specifying the source files explicitly where one object can be composed of several .cpp files. Is there a way to know that which source files this object is composed of before having a recursive make or just call the parent compilation rule/s for this object that was processed just before calling the link rule. I ask this for Makefile needs to be executed on its own for different objects.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question, but in general there's no built-in way to determine what prerequisite caused _some other rule_ to build.  You can do it with a very tricky use of `$(eval ...)`, if that's what you're really trying to do: in your compile rule you'd add something like `$(eval $@_SRC := $<)` then later you can use the variable `$($(obj_dir)/foo.o_SRC)` to retrieve it.